# Free software to replace SQL Developer?

Tags: database, sqldeveloper

As for a developer, the use of SQL Developer is almost daily. However, given that my laptop have only 1 gb ram, it is hard to open SQL Developer and Eclipse together. Do you have any lighter recommendation? Most importantly it should be free.

I cannot upgrade my laptop because it is company property and I've asked the hardware guy that they don't have extra ram or laptop inside the company.

Comment: What functions of SQL Developer are important for you? Query Builder? Or you just want to be able to run your queries against DB and see the result?

Comment: I just want to use the query against DB and pl/sql too.

Comment: Aren't you talking about SQL Management Studio??

Answer (score 2):

I gave up using any database clients in favor of [LinqPAD](http://www.linqpad.net):

1. It supports SQL Compact, SQL Express, SQL 2008, SQL 2005, SQL 2000, SQLite, MySQL and Oracle.
2. You can query OData (for example StackOverflow Data) and DataMarket online services.
3. You can choose between Linq-to-SQL (for supported  DB only: SQL Server, all editions including the compact one), Entities (all possible databases) and native SQL support.
4. You can quickly prototype code in C#, VB and F#.
5. It has a really powerful visualizer with different views (table, rich canvas etc.)

Comment: +1 for LinqPAD. Plus you can get your LINQ on. . .

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can give SQuirreL SQL a try. We used it in a company enviornment where we weren't allowed to install new software ourselves. 
It's not as fancy as SQL Developer, but it also works with many other databases like DB2 or MySQL.

As far as I can remember, memory consumption wasn't too bad, bad you have to try a current version and see if works for you.

It's based on Java, so you need a JRE though.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already running Eclipse, then why not add in [SQL Explorer](http://www.sqlexplorer.org/)?  It's perfectly fine for browsing databases and submitting queries, and you won't have to start another IDE.